# Is it possible to get objects from S3 bucket and directly use the results in a shell command as string?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, imagemagick

I'm using the official PHP SDK repository for AWS https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php

Everything works fine but I would like to know if I can access my objects directly, I would like to use it in this way:

```
require './start.php';
$bucket = 'cdn';

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT 'art' FROM ...");

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $row) {

    $result = $s3->getObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => 'uploads/media'. '/' .$row['art']
    ));

}

shell_exec('montage '.$result.' /var/www/html/out.jpg');
```

So basically the query select some images, it gets from S3, and those images are assembled together with [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) in a single JPEG (out.jpg).

Is it possible or simply I did it wrong?

Comment: you can mount your S3 bucket directly on your filesystem and access them as if they are on your harddrive.

Comment: @Dimi yes I have already done the connection...but I would like to know if is possible to do it after uploaded my images on the bucket